# How to get name of com-port c#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I tried like as:

```
foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
{
   Console.WriteLine("PortName: {0}", queryObj["PortName"]);
}
```

It gives me `not found` in console

Comment: I need to get number of port, COM1, COM2 etc

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, or at least get you pointed in the right direction:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher comPortSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE ConfigManagerErrorCode = 0");
foreach (ManagementObject service in comPortSearcher.Get())
{                
   Console.WriteLine(service.ToString());
}
```

Baically you need to specify the right query.

Comment: It gives me next inforation without port: `\\TMOM-PC\root\CIMV2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="USB\\VID_0403&PID_6001\\A900ER2T"`

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
            string[] portnames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();


             foreach( string port in portnames)
             {

                 Console.WriteLine(port);
             }
```

Comment: For what `ManagementObjectSearcher` in your code if you use `SerialPort.GetPortNames`?

Comment: @Piubur oh you right. my mistake.edited. if it helped you could you be a litlle kind and accept the answer? :)

Comment: It does not work for me, I have ID device and want to get port on that this device works